# Weka visualize data

Tags: java, weka, visualize

I have a question related to Weka. I have data and I want to visualize them. I use k-means for clustering. I found the option to visualize the data, but I would like something more than that. When you visualize the clusters if you right click on them, then a window appears. In that window there is some information, but I would like to see i.e the data that this point came from. Is there any way through Weka or i should write Java?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it but with no luck.

If I do not have matlab or R in my machine to plot data, I use GNUPlot ( http://www.gnuplot.info/ ) to plot data from command line and files.

Comment: I want to visualize the data and then click on them and see the data that the point came from... The best is to do it through java code, but I don't know if this happens, so i am searching for a tool.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ELKI or Processing Tool as an API in your Java program and can visualize your result. However, the visualization may not be interactive in ELKI but you can certainly extend the interactive property using customized methods while plugging the Processing Tool in your java code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write some code on your own but you may not need to start from scratch. You could use Weka's own code (it is open source) to develop a visualization plugin that satisfies your needs. Check the Wiki for more information and examples: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Explorer+visualization+plugins